# STM32F030F4P6 - Application Not Starting

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f0

I have been developing code to control an LCD using STM32F030F4P6 mcu. So far everything was working fine.

However I just added some new code with timer, and now when I uploaded the updated code, the system just stopped working. The only changes I made to the system were in code.

It seems as if my application is not executing as a test to light up an led right after entry to main is also not working. The mcu seems to be working since I am able to upload code to it.

```
#include "stm32f0xx_rcc.h"
#include "utilfunctions.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "sdcard.h"
#include "nokiac100.h"
#include "pwmdac.h"

void setupPeriphClocks(void);
void setupPins(void);
uint8_t checkClocks(void);

int main(void)
{
  setupPeriphClocks();
  setupPins();

  TEST_LED_ON;
```

This should turn on the led but nothing is happening.

Any idea what could be wrong here? i suspect it could be something related to a hard fault but have no idea how to check it.

Any help figuring this would be great!

**UPDATE**

So I found the culprit as the TIM1 ISR that I have written in my code. Commenting out the ISR makes my application compile and execute just fine. However including the ISR compiles fine, but the application does not run.

The ISR is

```
void TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM1, TIM_IT_CC3)==SET)
  {
    if(PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER<=PWMDAC_AUDIO_DATA_SIZE)
        {
            PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER++;
            if((PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER%512)==0)
            {
                //get next audio block
                PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_BLOCK_NUMBER++;
                //make sure sd card not being accessed by video system
                //before trying to read from it
                if(SDCARD_READ_ONGOING==0)
                {
                    SDCARD_Read_Block(PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_BLOCK_NUMBER*512, (uint8_t *)PWMDAC_AUDIO_BLOCK);
                }
                else
                {
                    PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_BLOCK_NUMBER--;
                    PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER--;
                }
            }
            TIMER_Timer1_SetDuty(PWMDAC_AUDIO_BLOCK[PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER%512]);
        }
        else
        {
            //end of audio samples. loop
            printf("looping audio\n");
            PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_BLOCK_NUMBER=PWMDAC_AUDIO_DATA_SD_STARTING_SECTOR;
            PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER=1;
            if(SDCARD_READ_ONGOING==0)
            {
                SDCARD_Read_Block(PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_BLOCK_NUMBER*512, (uint8_t *)PWMDAC_AUDIO_BLOCK);
                TIMER_Timer1_SetDuty(PWMDAC_AUDIO_BLOCK[PWMDAC_CURRENT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_NUMBER%512]);
            }
        }
    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1, TIM_IT_CC3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you not able to debug with breakpoints in the IDE? Could it be entering the ISR right at startup and getting stuck in there? Is the code inside the ISR good? Try commenting out the contents of the ISR except for clearing the interrupt and see it the application will run normally. If so then it's the code inside the ISR and not the interrupt itself.

Comment: the isr is there but you dont call it and just its presence prevents the program from running?

Comment: first step is to disassemble the binary or examine it and insure the vector table is correct.  that by adding code you or the tools didnt move it and it is still the first thing in the binary.  are you using one of the nucleo/mbed type ones or one that needs an stlink or are you downloading to ram and running there? or other?

Comment: Stupid question: did you even add the ISR to the interrupt vector table (or similar), so that the MCU knows where to jump when the interrupt gets triggered?

Comment: @Lundin I wish you could have written  your comment in a different way than such a waste of space fashion. And to answer you, yes I did. I guess only a 'professional' with 10+ years of claimed experience could have framed this in such a way!

Comment: @Ankit When doing any form of trouble-shooting, you have to check the basics first. Especially since failing to add the ISR to the vector table would result in exactly the kind of behavior you describe. It is an easy mistake to make, we have all done it many times.

Comment: @Ankit, you have both interrupts: NonMaskableInt_IRQn and HardFault_IRQn - which are called if occur some of periferals errors linked to it one. So you can implement handlers and see with debuger or leds is they are called or not.

Comment: I see that you are doing a lot in the ISR.  Reading blocks from a SdCard. It can be that the time consumed in the ISR doesn't leave any time for the mainloop to run.